# Xcode 8.1 SourceKitService loads CPU completely

Tags: sourcekitservice, xcode8

SourceKitService eats CPU resource. Sometimes it loads the processor completely, when I work in Xcode 8.1 (Version 8.1 (8B62)). MacBook (macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555)) slows down and gets very hot.

1. How to fix it?
2. If I remove SourseKitservise how it will affect the work of Xcode?

[image]

Comment: I noticed that SourceKitService keep hugging the CPU at around 100% when no project is open, also never-ending indexing. I found that cleaning the project fix these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided this problem by reinstalling Xcode 8.1:

1. Open Application folder in Finder.
2. Find Xcode file and Move to Trash, then empty the Trash
3. Go to App Store Find "Xcode" in Search
4. Install Xcode

After installation, no need to enter Apple IDs in Preference>Account (but You should check whether all okay)

After reinstalling Xcode 8.1 SourseKitservise loads the processor on 15-20% (see screenshot)[image: SourseKitservise]

Answer (score 0):

Just force quit SourceKitService, it will restart again, without any issues.